# Which published D&D adventures feature a dungeon with water-based mechanics?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

I'm looking at designing a water-themed dungeon for use in 5e, along similar lines as Zelda's various Water Temples. I've been looking for any published adventures which already do something similar to use as inspiration, but have come up empty. Any recommendations?

Suggestions from any edition of D&D / Pathfinder are welcome, with no restrictions in terms of PC level. Ideally the dungeon should have some (but not all) sections underwater, with ways to alter the flow / water-level in order to reach certain areas. Official WoTC / Paizo content preferred but third party content also welcome.

Comment: I've avoided reading Saltmarsh as I'm a player in a campaign there currently, otherwise I agree that would've probably been ideal. I can't access the chat from this PC but might drop in later.

Comment: Do you mean mechanics about operating/living in water above and beyond what is published in the core rules?

Comment: I'm referring to mechanics of the dungeon itself - traps, obstacles, features etc. - as opposed to 'game mechanics' such as the rules for underwater combat / drowning.

Comment: How many examples do you need?  If you're including 3rd party content there is a lot.  Asking for all would likely be construed as a shopping question, and those aren't a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 2):

A brief adventure with water dungeons/areas is [Curse of the Sea Witch](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product_info.php?products_id=243417&).  It has an undersea village, a portal to the elemental plane of water, and a few other underwater surprises.

It's part of the *Tides of Fate* series of adventures that are all coastal themed.  It's a third party author and publisher.